# Combining a lib and it's debug symbols to produce source-interleaved disassembly

Tags: glibc, disassembly, objdump

I've both `libc6` and `libc6-dbg` packages installed. What I want to do is to display the disassembly of `ld.so` with source interleaved. I also have the glibc source placed in a chroot, reachable at the exact location as displayed by `DW_AT_comp_dir` in debug symbols.

Could someone tell me--if it's possible--how to output the source-interleaved disassembly of `ld.so` library please? I know I could use `objdump -S`, but how would I point it to the separate debug symbol file available?

Answer (score 0):

The best match I could find was to use GDB:

- `gdb /the/original/library`
- Use `add-symbol-file` command to locate the add the symbol file that was installed as part of `-dbg` package (use `dpkg -L the-package-name-dbg` to find all files installed as part of the package). This command would also need an address to load the symbols from. This address can be found out from `readelf -a /the/original/library`, and is most likely the load address of the text segment
- Install package source with `apt-get source the-package-name`. This will download the source in the current working directory
- Use `dir` command in GDB to locate the source downloaded above
- Now use `disas/m function_name` so that GDB will display a the disassembly, ordered by source lines